# Why Laravel store() outside the public folder?

Tags: laravel

I have a form where you can upload single images. In my saveImage() method I validate the image and use the Laravel function store() to store the image.

```
$this->formdataImage['image']->store('images');
```

Here is the return value of the store() method: `"images/hE9kU1LkKOXedCPV8JV3L7DNBZGDQjQR3wXePynX.png"` The image was also successfully saved in the folder storage/app/images/.

If I now want to display the image on the website with: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/hE9kU1LkKOXedCPV8JV3L7DNBZGDQjQR3wXePynX.png` I get a 404, which is correct. The symlink I set just before with `php artisan storage:link` connects: `/public/storage` with `/storage/app/public`. And the image is under storage/app/images. So outside the public folder.

Am I doing something wrong or is that the way Laravel wants it? For security reasons, for example? And I have to copy the image into the public folder afterwards?
I use Laravel 8.

Comment: So you need to store inside storage directory and you need to display it in frontend without exposing actual url ??

Answer (score 0):

For the uploaded image to be exposed via the symlink, it needs to be in the `storage/app/public` folder

Set the path in store to `public/images`

```
$this->formdataImage['image']->store('public/images');
```

it will return `"public/images/hE9kU1LkKOXedCPV8JV3L7DNBZGDQjQR3wXePynX.png"` as the path and accessible via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/hE9kU1LkKOXedCPV8JV3L7DNBZGDQjQR3wXePynX.png`